# How to check if (Sub)Array exists in Array

Tags: c, windows

I need something between `strstr` and `memcmp` for checking if an array exists in a range of memory.

Example what I want to achieve:

```
BYTE a[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
BYTE b[] = { 0x02, 0x03 };
if (mem_in_mem(a, b, 4 * sizeof(BYTE)) == 0) {
    printf("b is in memory range of a\n");
}
```

Any ideas how I can something like that?
(Should work with windows)

Comment: You could write that function, sure. Why not `memcmp` and advance a character each time until you've checked the whole buffer?

Comment: Unfortunately, the proposed `mem_in_mem` function is not told the length of the (Sub)Array it is supposed to match.

Comment: @tadman Yeah I thought about this - would be easy BUT I need this in a very performance critical case so I was hoping there is a high optimized method of doing this.

Comment: You could read up on string searching algorithms, there's a number to pick from, and adapt that code to work on binary buffers by not stopping on a null byte. The thing that will kill performance the most is mis-aligned reads when using 64-bit values to do your searching, something that's way faster than hammering byte-by-byte through this thing, but comparing `int` vs `int` can narrow down your search space by a factor of 4 or 8.

Comment: Optimise by checking the first byte before committing to an expensive  function call to `memcmp`.

Comment: At looks like perhaps you want to implement the [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).  Any way around, though, the function needs a way to know the boundaries of both the target array and the test array.

Comment: @WeatherVane you realise memcmp checks the first byte too right?

Comment: @immibis in *your* library, perhaps, but it still requires a function call which can be avoided if the simple test fails.

Comment: @WeatherVane So why check the first byte and not the first two or three? That's a rather arbitrary threshold and since memcmp is an intrinsic in production compilers these days anyhow it won't even do any good.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sure, but you could easily do the check for the second byte too if that would actually bring such a big performance boost - you'd just have to key it to the length. Anyhow this was a rhetoric question to show what kind of premature optimisation this is. There's no point doing this on any modern compiler. Don't try to be cleverer than the compiler, it's likely to fail, if you want to optimise some code, measure twice, change it once.

Comment: @Voo you mean compilers for major desktop computers? I have worked with cross compilers for embedded, and you get what you get. I thoroughly hate leaving the compiler to do the work, and was taught not to. C is a low level language and the code produced should be what I intended it to be.

Comment: @Weather If you "optimize" things on what you think will happen, there's a large chance you'll worsen the results. You might want C compilers to generate code to be "what you intend it to be", but this is just one of the many many examples where your expectations don't match reality (gcc for ARM does this optimisation for example). If you want to optimise performance you'll have to see what the actual hotspots are, what code the compiler generates and only then think about adopting the code to optimize.

Comment: @Voo the kind of thing I mean, is say, calculating within a loop what you can calulate outside the loop, such as an end condition. I would happily disable all compiler optimisations. If I think a loop should be unrolled, I will unroll it myself. I came to C from assembler, as did C itself, and I am no fan of a 'modern' compiler producing code that is very different from the code I wrote. If I wanted that, I would not be using C.

Comment: @Weather If you think you're smarter than modern compilers you're horribly mistaken. Do you know which microops have false dependencies in specific processors? Do you know how many instructions of what kind can be issued in the same cycle? Because a modern compiler does. If you're really good you can improve upon the generated assembly in special situations if you put enough effort in, but the time where programmers could produce better code than a compiler in the standard case is gone for a while now.

Comment: PS: You obviously can disable almost all compiler optimisations by building with -O0 and co - you're welcome to see if that results in a faster program :-)

Comment: @Voo I think you mean compiler *writers* but I do not think I am smarter, perhaps as a former writer of assemblers and disassemblers and embedded code emulators *as* smart. I only know how I want to use C, not have some smartass rewrite it for me. But you are right: that is what C has become.

Comment: @Weather Not one compiler writer knows all of that either. Compilers have large amounts of information coded into them, that they get directly from the chip companies and many people spend many hours to improve code gen. And personally I find that great: The only reason to write C is if I need control over memory layout and/or maximum performance. Clever compilers don't harm the first and greatly help me achieve the latter. But we're really getting off-topic.

Comment: @Voo obviously the compiler will generate the right instructions for the target but that was not my original point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `mem_in_mem` should take the size of both arrays.  Here is a simplistic implementation:

```
#include <string.h>

void *mem_in_mem(const void *haystack, size_t n1, const void *needle, size_t n2) {
    const unsigned char *p1 = haystack;
    const unsigned char *p2 = needle;

    if (n2 == 0)
        return (void*)p1;
    if (n2 > n1)
        return NULL;

    const unsigned char *p3 = p1 + n1 - n2 + 1;
    for (const unsigned char *p = p1; (p = memchr(p, *p2, p3 - p)) != NULL; p++) {
        if (!memcmp(p, p2, n2))
            return (void*)p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

You would invoke it this way:

```
BYTE a[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 };
BYTE b[] = { 0x02, 0x03 };
if (mem_in_mem(a, sizeof a, b, sizeof b)) {
    printf("b is in memory range of a\n");
}
```

Comment: Just as `int *ptr = malloc(8);` does not need a cast, neither does `return (void*)p;`  Perhaps window's C is picky?

Comment: Ah, I see the need for the cast, to discard the `const`!